# Variational Calculus Optimization Problem with x-independent Lagrangian Solution via Beltrami Identity

Tags: analysis, functional-equations, variational-analysis

> Optimize $$\int_0^1 y^2 (y')^2 dx$$
> subject to $y(0)=0, y(1)=1$

For x-independent Lagrangians it is easier to use Beltrami Identity: $$ F-y'{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}}=C $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Beltrami's formula

$$
y^2(y')^2-y'(y^2 2 y')= -y^2(y')^2= C
$$

then

$$
\left(\frac 12 \frac{d}{dx}y^2\right)^2= C_1
$$

or

$$
\frac 12 \frac{d}{dx}y^2 = C_2
$$

and

$$
\frac 13 y^3=C_3x+C_4
$$

and with the boundary conditions

$$
y = \sqrt[3]{x}
$$